# Add and remove domain users from local administrators group on remote computers using c# and WMI

Tags: c#, wmi

I am working on a small utility that will be used to manage domain users that are in the local administrators group on a given remote computer. I want to be able to take a computer name and username from user input (textboxes) and either add or remove the user from the administrators group on the given computer depending which radio button is chosen (either add or remove). I have looked around and haven't been able to find much of anything on how to do this using WMI and c#. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is WMI mandatory? You could also give `net user` a go ([How to Use the Net User Command](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251394)). You can then execute the net user command though a command prompt which you can launch using your program.
To add a user to a group (your new account to the local admin group), you can use [Net Group](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754051%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)